# bitbucket how to return branch from "merged" into "active"

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket

i had `master` branch (with the production version)

i had `test` branch for the development needs

decided to make `master` for the development needs

`test` for the pre production tests on real server equal for production

`prod` branch for the code passed `test` branch - really production code

What i did through bitbucket interface:

1. from the `master` branch was created `prod` branch (to have in it current production version of the code)
2. then i merged `test` branch into the `master` (to have in `master` my current development)
   at this moment bitbucket decided that `test` and `prod` branches not required anymore and marked them as "merged" and removed them from the "active" branches list, BUT i need them !!!

as a solution i see following:

1. create `test` branch from the current `master` - since they are equal at the moment
2. on my local PC from the local `master` create branch `prod` and push it to the bitbucket (i think when i was cloning repository i wasnt influenced by the .gitignore, right ? so my local `master` has the state of the `origin/master` before merge)

please answer me if I'm right about the solution and have another question:

is there a way to restore my branches from the "merged" to "active" by means of bitbucket in case this happen again ?

P.S.: may be i shouldn't do anything with them, because they are still available in pull request dropdowns, so i can merge other branches with them and if i do so, they (`prod` and  `test` branches) again appear in the active branches list ?

Comment: For future work, consider using SourceTree. It has a super intuitive UI, which prevents problems like this :)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to list your test and prod branches as Active instead of Merged?

Answer (score 7):

If you hover your mouse over `Active` or `Merged` tabs, there are tooltip(s) that explain their purpose:

Merged: Branches that are not ahead of the main branch

Active: Branches that are ahead of the main branch

So if the main/master branch already includes everything that is there in the branch in question (for example, a brand new branch), then it is shown in the `Merged` tab.

Answer (score 2):

so the problem looks like not exist.
bitbucket just scared me a bit, all branches exists where they should, bit bucket just decided to kind of "soft replace" branches in it interface from active to merged.

`$ git branch -a`

```
*master
test

remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/prod
remotes/origin/test
```